# styled-components won't work with multiple ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styling, styled-components, react-dom

So I'm building a RubyOnRails application with React in the frontend. I have several microfrontends and I render each of them separately. Like this:

index.html.erb

```
<div id="app-header" />
<div id="app-content" />
```

Header.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const StyledHeader = styled.div`
   // ...
`;

const Header = () => {
  return <StyledHeader>...</StyledHeader>;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Header />, 
    document.getElementById('app-header'));
});
```

App.jsx.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const StyledApp = styled.div`
   // ...
`;

const App = () => {
  return <StyledApp>...</StyledApp>;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App />, 
    document.getElementById('app-content'));
});
```

The problem is that it looks like styled-components one renders the last styles from ReactDOM.render.

So in this case only `app-content` would be styled. If I remove it, than `app-header` is styled. I inspected the elements and it looks like the styles from `app-header` are not in the DOM when `app-content` is present. It's like it gets overridden.

I can't make the content and the header under the same root component because the content is not always React.

Is there a way of making the styles work without breaking this structure?